# spring transaction at service layer

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-aop

In our application we are applying spring declarative transactions using annotations at service layer.

Here i am not getting any idea on how to handle exceptions properly.

What exactly my requirement is when dao layer throws any hibernate exception we are rolling back the transaction, but in one case i am getting `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException` because there is a unique index violation happening. So what i would like to do here is i want to catch `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException` exception at service class and have to rethrow the application specific exception to controller.

But whats happening here is as we have transaction demarcation at service layer class the session is flushing at service layer(ie when tx commits) after executing the method, as a result i cant catch it into the same method and it is directly propagating to the controller.

Please suggest me work around on this.

also seeking one more clarification, suppose i have a method like below

```
@Transactional(value="transactionManager",readOnly = false, propagation    = Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackFor = HibernateException.class)  
public SomeDTO editObject(SomeDTO someDto, String user)   throws        EditException    {         
    try{
        /*  
        call to dao.edit(); 
        another call to anotherDao.addEditsTOAnotherTable();
        some business logic*/    
    } catch(HibernateException e){   
    } catch(InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException ie){}    
}
```

Can i catch exceptions as above. Note: I am not handling or throwing any exceptions from dao. Also there is no session cache mechanisms like `FlushMode.ALWAYS` etc at dao layer as it will flush during `tx.commit()`.

Comment: Check that you won't break the unique index before inserting. Or call flush() explicitely.

Comment: I just want to convey to user about the unique index violation when ever it happens. Pls let me know if we have any other alternate of handling it instead of flushing.

Comment: As I said: you could check that you won't break the unique index before inserting

Comment: @JBNizet checking before inserting doesn't mean an extra va-et-vien to the database which means an extra query to execute ?

Comment: @user3871322 I have the exact same issue. Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

By default `@Transactional` will rollback for any `RuntimeException`, and since `HibernateException` is a `RuntimeException` , roll back will be done automaticaly and you don't have to add `rollbackFor = HibernateException.class`
You can handle Exception this way:

```
try{
}catch(InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException e){
 throw new YourApplicationExceptionNotUniqueIndex();
}
```

and :

`YourApplicationExceptionNotUniqueIndex` shoud `extends` `RuntimeException` that way you wil have a rollback at your sevice layer and you can catch the exception at your Controller .

Comment: But here i need to catch the HibernateException and want to rethrow ApplicationSpecificException. That's why i have a catch block for HIbernateException in the service method. But i am unable to catch the hibernate exception eventhough any HibernateException occurs. I can only catch it when i explicitly flush session in dao. I am wondering why i could not able to catch it when tx.commit() happens.

Comment: InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException  is also a Runtime Exception.

Answer (score -1):

Better to handle check all the database constraints before editing into database